# How to make twice daily backup of SQL Server database?

Tags: sql-server, database-backups

I use SQL Server and try to make daily backups of my database. Of course I need to backup twice, at 9am and 5pm. I use Maintenance Plans such as this image.

[image]

SQL Server Agent service is running.When I try to execute this plan get error:

> ### TITLE: Execute Maintenance Plan
>
> Execution failed. See the maintenance plan and SQL Server Agent job
>   history logs for details.
>
> ------------------------------ ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> Job 'Periodic backup.Subplan_1' failed. (SqlManagerUI)

What is problem?

Comment: Did you check the SQL Server logs?

Comment: How can i do this?